# Redirecting a wordpress blog

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a wordpress installation that is located in the root folder: mydomain.com

This website has a blog that is directed to mydomain.com/blog

What I would like  to achieve is to redirect all traffic that goes to mydomain.com/blog to another wordpress installation that has a blog and located on a temporary domain on my server - server.myserverdomain.com/~seconsite/blog

I would like to also keep the main website domain mydomain.com/blog

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

**Redirect by PHP**

```
header("Location: server.myserverdomain.com/~seconsite/blog");
die();
```

**Redirect by HTML**

Method 1 :

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://server.myserverdomain.com/~seconsite/blog/" />
```

Method 2 :

```
<script>window.top.location = 'http://server.myserverdomain.com/~seconsite/blog';</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is

**Redirection by JavaScript**

Make one file named index.html, in which put html,head and body tags and also put javascript code as below

```
<script>
window.location="http://UrlToRedirect";
</script>
```

Put this index.html file into your /www/blog directory or whichever directory you have for mydomain.com/blog.

And make sure you don't have any other file named as index in that directory except this one which you will prepare.

And you are good to go.

Comment: thanks,

then user will be redirected and see the domain as: server.myserverdomain.com/~seconsite/blog.

I need a solution that actually shows the visitor the same root domain

Comment: Apparently, that will happen with all possible solutions for your problem.